# can't run customtkinter with .exe

Tags: python, tkinter, auto-py-to-exe, customtkinter

when I try to convert my python file into .exe using auto-py-to-exe an error occure:

```
Traceback (most recent call last): 
File "Jumper.py", line 5,
in File "C:\Users\Clowny\output\Jumper\customtkinter_init_.py", line 10, in 
from .appearance_mode_tracker import AppearanceModeTrackerù 
File "C:\Users\Clowny\output\Jumper\customtkinter\appearance_mode_tracker.py", line 3, in 
from distutils.version import StrictVersion as Version 
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'distutils'
```

I already used the documentation steps but it still doesn't working.
can anyone help me?

Comment: what Python version do you use? `distutils` is deprecated in `3.11` and it will be removed in `3.12`

Comment: Did you use the latest `customtkinter` and `setuptools` modules?

Comment: I don't have such error when I convert a simple `customtkinter` script to exe using `auto-py-to-exe`.

Comment: I fixed it guys, I had to encorporate the customtkinter's directory